# System Calls: Interpreting ktrace output

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, ln

While learning for an upcoming exam, I encoutered the following problem:

Which was the UNIX command that the user tried to execute? What's happening in the lines that are marked with a * ? What was the problem?

I've figured out that the user probably wanted to execute something like

**ln -s dir ls**

But that doesn't give me the expected output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to answer the question myself.

The command that the user tries to execute is **`ln ls dir`**, which basically targets using the word dir as an 'alias' for the ls command.

That goes wrong because the user tries to operate in a directory which doesn't grant write-permissions to him (most probably the `/bin` directory), which means that he isn't able to create a file (the hardlink) in this directory.

By using ktrace/kdump I managed to reproduce the output:

```
  [...]
 *77019 ln       CALL  stat(0x7fffffffebab,0x7fffffffd668)
  77019 ln       NAMI  "test/ls"
  77019 ln       RET   stat 0
 *77019 ln       CALL  lstat(0x7fffffffebb3,0x7fffffffd668)
  77019 ln       NAMI  "test/dir"
  77019 ln       RET   lstat -1 errno 2 No such file or directory
 *77019 ln       CALL  stat(0x7fffffffebb3,0x7fffffffd668)
  77019 ln       NAMI  "test/dir"
  77019 ln       RET   stat -1 errno 2 No such file or directory
 *77019 ln       CALL  lstat(0x7fffffffebb3,0x7fffffffd668)
  77019 ln       NAMI  "test/dir"
  77019 ln       RET   lstat -1 errno 2 No such file or directory
 *77019 ln       CALL linkat(AT_FDCWD,0x7fffffffebab,AT_FDCWD,0x7fffffffebb3,0x400)
  77019 ln       NAMI  "test/ls"
  77019 ln       NAMI  "test/dir"
  77019 ln       RET   linkat -1 errno 13 Permission denied
  [...]
 *77019 ln       CALL  exit(0x1)
```

The steps marked with a star can be explained as follows:

The first syscall is to gather the inode information of the original file (´`test/ln`). 
Next, it checks whether the target file (`test/dir`) already exists, either as a named file (`stat`) or as a symbolic link (`lstat`).

Because this is not the case, the process tries to link the files (`linkat`- in the original example: `link`). As mentioned earlier this goes wrong because of permissions.

The process finally finishes with a negative exit code.

Comment: A link is not an alias. It might be in Windows, but not in Unixoids.